# SQLAlchemy how do I copy an auto-incrementing primary key column?

Tags: python, sql, sqlalchemy

It seems like a bit of a workaround to commit changes, query the database for the key, and insert it somewhere else.

I assumed one should use the [synonym()](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/orm/mapped_attributes.html) function for this, but it doesn't seem to have any effect, i.e. my synonymous column doesn't exist when querying the database afterwards.

E.g.

```
class MyClass(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'my_table'

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
    job_status = Column(String(50))

    other_id = synonym("id")
```

Comment: It is a bit unclear what you're after. Synonyms are not DB synonyms, but mirror a persisted attribute at the ORM level.

Comment: What function am I then looking for, to manifest an `other_id` column that mirrors `id`?

Comment: Will it _always_ be the same as `id`, or can it change independently?

Comment: For now, I actually don't know. Is there a big difference in how to pull it off?